# How do I reduce the gap space when wrapping using flex: wrap

Tags: html, css

How do I reduce or remove this space when wrapping? What also causes this behavior.

Here is the screenshots and code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAPKO.png)

[image]

```css
#gallery .card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.card-container .card {
  border: solid black 1px;
  height: 40%;
  width: 30%;
  flex: 1 1 21rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="gallery">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the HTML as well?

Comment: The provided code doesnt produce the problem. If I run the code snippet, there is no large gap.

Comment: gap:10px. you just have to remove this or reduce and gap will be less.reduce.

Answer (score -2):

Write CSS in this format:

```
#gallery .card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.card-container .card {
  border: solid black 1px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged; please try to explain what you've changed and why.  If you can provide your solution as a StackSnippet, as the OP has been kind enough to do, that would also be appreciated.